# what does "70A moy/arit 90A eff" on a high-current automotive lead-acid battery charger mean?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, automotive

I have a huge (28 kg mass) automotive high-current battery charger, and its current delivering capabilities are described like that:

```
70A moy/arit 90A eff
```

What do these mysterious abbreviations "moy", "arit" and "eff" exactly mean, and how much current can this beast really deliver, 70A, 90A, what's the difference between the first and second number?

Here is a photo, so you have an idea what kind of device it is:
[image: http://telto.nazwa.pl/allegro/15.10.2010/d/dscf1313.jpg]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think those are French abbreviations. I believe "moy/arit" is an abbreviation of "moyenne arithmétique," meaning "arithmetic mean," or average.

I'm not sure about "eff," but I bet it's an abbreviation for a French word for "peak."

Comment: literally had 4 coworkers from belgium with me 6 hour ago, if only this had been posted in time!

Comment: @Kortuk - Weren't they Dutch-speaking? Belgium is a complicated country! (Though I don't know any other country with so many people speaking at least three languages)

Comment: @stevenvh, my company is almost exclusively French speaking. I have met 1 person whom was primary language dutch of 30.

Answer (score 1):

"moy"  or "moyenne" most likely refers to "average" and "eff" or "effusion" is most likely put here to signify "burst"... as in some sort of vehicle jump mode.

(idea stolen from my dinky battery charger at home that has 10A continuous and 30A "burst" capability for helping to jump a car)